# I got exception when try to create new API in WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2 on Windows 10

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have installed WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2 in Windows 10,I tried to create a new API but i got this exception as showed in the screenshot .

[image: Screenshot of integration studio error]

This is the exception code :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index out of bounds
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4888)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4822)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.getItem(CTabFolder.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.getItem(MultiPageEditorPart.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setPageText(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1101)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.createPage0(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:336)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.createPages(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:365)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:995)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
```

Comment: try to download the sample from the official documentation and open it in your environment

Comment: same error i got !

Comment: try to open the project in the cmd and run `mvn clean install` command. and update the question with the result

Comment: How did you install Integration Studio? Did you install with the correct MSI with the correct architecture (e.g: x64)?

Comment: Yes ,i have installed it with the right MSI .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespaces for the workspace directory path was the cause of this exception .
I change the path with another Workspace that doesn't contain any whitespaces and it works fine .

[image: screenshot of Workspace folder path]